# sql left join with several conditions in "on clause" versus where statment

Tags: sql, join, left-join, where-clause

I would appreciate any input. I am combining several questions i have into a simple query.

suppose table T1 records income growth across time for employees that are identified by an ID. there is one ID and income per day in the table.

I want to create another column next to each employee per day in which i find their maximum income in a 7 days look-ahead window, if their baseline income (initial income in the 7 day window)  was larger than 10 and if their incomes in 7 days-look-ahead window was larger than the baseline income. I am also only interested in creating this maximum income for records from 2016 forward.

is the query below correct?

```
select ID,income,Date,max(income2) 
       from ( select T1.ID , T1.income, T1.Date , T2.income as income2  
              From T1 
                left join T1 as T2 
                   on T1.ID = T2.ID 
                  and T2.date between T1.Date and T1.Date + 7 
                  and T1.income > T2.income 
                  and T1.income > 10
                 where T1.date > DATE('2016-01-01') ) g 
        group by T1.ID , T1.income, T1.Date
```

Comment: What database and version are you using? It looks good as it is, but MAX(income2) may be NULL if there are no matching samples, is this what you want?

Comment: that is okay if there is no match and to have a null. This example is hypothetical as i cant share my actual data-base online .i am using sql spark to do the operations. Can you tell me if the "logic" is okay ?

Comment: it seems ok, but you'll have to test it on data and ensure you're getting the results you expect